# 'package:flutter/src/widget/text.dart': Fasiled assertion: line 378 pos 10; 'data != null': A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I got red screen on the mobile phone when accessing record_patien.

here's the code

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/models/sensor.dart';
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/models/user.dart';
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/screens/authenticate/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebase_auth;
import 'package:sensor_detak_jantung/services/db_path.dart';

class RecordPatient extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecordPatient({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordPatient createState() => _RecordPatient();
}

class _RecordPatient extends State<RecordPatient> {

  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  final _auth = firebase_auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final TextEditingController tokenController = TextEditingController();
  User userInfo;
  firebase_auth.User _user;
  Sensor sensorInfo;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String bpm;
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    this._user = _auth.currentUser;
    if(_user != null) {
```

This is where i try to get BPM value

```
      databaseReference.child('Sensor').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        bpm = snapshot.value['BPM']['Data'];
      });
```

This is for user, this code run smoothly on other class.

```
      databaseReference.child(USER_KEY).child(_user.uid).once().then((snapshot) {
        userInfo = User.fromSnapshot(snapshot);
        setState(() { });
      });

    }
  }

  AppBar title(){
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red[400],
      elevation: 0.0,
      title: Text('Hi ${userInfo?.userName}'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          label: Text('logout'),
          onPressed: () async {
            _auth.signOut().then((value) {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()));
              setState(() {});
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print (bpm);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22.0, 0.0, 22.0, 22.0),
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            title(),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            Text (bpm),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this happen when i try to get `Sensor` value and `users` value.

im still learning and experimenting, if someone can explain me why this error happen in easy way is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the error, the Text widget is getting a null value, which is an error when we pass something like this to the text `Text(null)`.
In your code, this is only possible at this text widget where bpm might be null.

```
Text (bpm),
```

So you can simply do this,

```
databaseReference.child('Sensor').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        bpm = snapshot.value['BPM']['Data']??"";
      });
```

to fix the error.

Comment: I believe its the same code that i use to get the bpm in the first place. but why u put ?? in the end? since most of my code is part from different tutorial. So i try to learn it.

Comment: I added the null check in the second line where bpm is assigned so that it can't be null. ?? is null check operator, which checks if something is null, and if it is, it simply returns what's written after that, as in this case "".

Comment: Ah i see, and is it possible to update the value of bpm each time database changed without refreshing the screen

Comment: You can use StreamBuilder for that instead of FutureBuilder. Firebase also provides stream and you can search more about them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `snapshot.value['BPM']['Data'];` returns `null`, so your Text() widget has `null` as its value, which is not allowed. You should add a null check before assigning the value of bpm to the Text widget, perhaps something like this:

```dart
SizedBox(height: 40),
title(),
SizedBox(height: 40),
(bpm == null)?Text ("No BPM received"):Text(bpm),
```